# Liquid Layout IE Problems, of course (Newbie)

Tags: javascript, html, css, liquid-layout

I'm new to CSS, never created a layout before and I'm having some issues with my first one in Internet Explorer. I think it looks good in Firefox though.
I have done a lot of reading about HTML and CSS before starting the layout so I knew IE had some bugs but even after making the layout and researching the issues none of the resolutions seem to be working. Im hoping someone here can help.

TL;DR: New layout not working in IE, need help(did research)

---

Problem 1: In IE the 2 right sidebars are too wide compared to Firefox. Everything else appears normal, just those 2 are too wide which is affecting the layout
Problem 2: When the window width is below 1024 it is supposed to switch from container1.css to container2.css effectively changing the container properties to better display in smaller resolutions. Works great in Firefox, but in IE it seems to remove the container period leaving the contents to flow throughout the entire window.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>My Liquid Layout</TITLE>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="LiquidLayout.css" />
<link id="container1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="container1.css" />
<link id="container2"  rel="alternate" type="text/css" href="container2.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--    

var css = "container1";
function changeStyle(styleSheet)
{
if(styleSheet == css)
    return;
var selected = document.getElementById(styleSheet);
var current = document.getElementById(css);
if(!selected)
{
    selected = current.cloneNode(true);
    selected.id=styleSheet;
    selected.setAttribute("href",current.getAttribute("href").replace(new
   RegExp(css),styleSheet));
}
    current.setAttribute("rel","stylesheet1");
    selected.setAttribute("rel","stylesheet");
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(selected);
    css = styleSheet;
    }

function windowSize()
{
var windowWidth;
var windowHeight;
windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

if (document.body && document.body.offsetWidth)
{
    windowWidth = document.body.offsetWidth;
    windowHeight = document.body.offsetHeight;
}
if (document.compatMode=='CSS1Compat' &&
    document.documentElement &&
    document.documentElement.offsetWidth ) 
{
    windowWidth = document.documentElement.offsetWidth;
    windowHeight = document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
}
if (window.innerWidth && window.innerHeight) 
{
    windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
    windowHeight= window.innerHeight;
}

if(windowWidth < 1024)
changeStyle('container2');
else if(windowWidth >= 1024)
changeStyle('container1');
}

window.onresize = new Function("windowSize()");
//-->   

</script>   

</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div id = "container">
<div id = "header"><p id = "size"></p></div>
<div id = "content">
    <div id = "menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Video</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">IGN</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id = "sidebox"></div>
    <div class = "column" id = "sidebar"></div>
    <div class = "column" id = "main"></div>    
</div>
<div id = "footer"></div>
</div>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

The main CSS is:

```
body 
{
background-color:gray;
margin: 0px;
text-align: center;
}

#header
{
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
background-color: yellow;

}

#content
{
padding-top:5px;
padding-bottom:0px;
padding-right:5px;
padding-left:5px;
min-height: 768px;
}

#menu
{
width: 66%;
height: 250px;
background-color: blue;
float: left;
}

#sidebox
{
width: 34%;
height: 250px;
background-color: red;
float: right;
display: inline;
}

#sidebar
{
width: 34%;
background-color: red;
height: 100%;
float: right;
}

#main
{
width: 65%;
height: 100%;
background-color: green;
float: left;
}
```

If anyone can please offer some advice on fixing these issues in IE I would appreciate it!
Any suggestions for improvement are welcome as well

Comment: You didn't use a doctype, so IE uses the wrong box model (it's running in [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html)).

Comment: Also, look into using jQuery instead of vanilla javascript.  jQuery helps fix a lot of the incompatibilities with IE and other cross-browser issues

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which version of IE, so I'm guessing you've only checked the most recent version?

Add a doctype as suggested, and you should be ok in IE9, but if you're supporting other versions of IE as well you are going to want some way of targeting each version independently as they all have different and progressively worse bugs. Occasionally, something will work in IE7 but not IE8, but generally as you head towards IE6 your problems will multiply exponentially, especially with a liquid layout.

I'd recommend using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/), which will add different class names to the HTML element depending on the version of IE in use. It also does a bunch of other stuff like making HTML5 elements styleable in older IE as well, so it is worth using, even without any of the other feature tests it offers. I can see you aren't using any HTML5 elements, but I don't know if that's your whole layout, or just the beginnings of it...

You'll probably also want to use [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) so that most useful CSS3 features can be used in IE8 and below as well, although you need to use a JS library, such as jQuery for this, so it may or may not be useful. There isn't any CSS3 in your CSS, but again, your example could be much simplified

In terms of improvements to your code, you don't need to include HTML comments in your script tags `<!--` and haven't since the days of like IE4 or something. Additionally, your  should go at the bottom of the `<body>` (just before the closing `</body>`) for performance reasons, rather than in the `<head>`, and if you use the HTML5 doctype (which you can still use even if you aren't planning on using any HTML5 elements) you don't need to specify a type attribute on the `<script>` element. In JavaScript, the opening curly brackets should go on the same line as the function definition or conditional, so do:

```
if (condition) {
```

or:

```
function something() {
```

and not:

```
if (condition)
{
```

or:

```
function something()
{
```

This is usually ok most of the time, but it can produce bugs that are very hard to spot, so it is worth getting into the habit of doing it all the time. And when attaching an event listener, you don't need to specify `new Function("function_name")`, you can just attach the function directly:

```
window.onresize = windowSize();
```

Also, in CSS, zero values do not need to specify measurement units, so you can just have `0` instead of `0px`...

Answer (score 0):

If you have copy and pasted the entirity then your missing a doctype making IE render in quirksmode.

I would suggest adding the HTML5 doctype to the top of your document `<!DOCTYPE html>`

[More information on quirks mode can be found here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html)